# Does it make sense that it take spark 4 seconds to count 13M lines?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to spark, and currently testing pySpark. It runs slower then I've expected, and I was wondering whether I set it up correctly.

### My problem:

I have an RDD consist of 57 partitions (~30Mb each), all are cached (total size in memory is 1700MB).  The RDD holds 13M strings, ~300 characters each. So generally speaking not a big data set. 
so why does it takes 4 seconds to run count() ?

I've checked the UI, and it seems that for the 'count' job it runs 57 tasks (as expected), and each task takes 0.6 seconds, which seems very slow to me.

I'm running on Google cloud, on top of Mesos, with 1 master and 2 slaves. Each instance has 8 cores, and 30 GB of RAM.

### My questions:

1. Is 0.6 seconds for each task make sense?
2. according to the UI, each executor spent 18 seconds running tasks. Given 8 cores per node, this should take 2.25 seconds. So how did we get to 4 seconds at the end?

### The Code:

```
import time
GCS_CONNECTOR_HADOOP_CONF = {
    'fs.gs.impl': 'com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem',
    'fs.gs.project.id': 'xxx',
    'fs.gs.system.bucket': 'xxx',
    'fs.gs.working.dir': 'spark',
    'fs.gs.auth.service.account.email': 'xxx',
    'fs.gs.auth.service.account.keyfile': 'xxxx'
}


def get_rdd_from_gcs_uris(spark_context,
                          gcs_uris,
                          hadoop_conf,
                          input_format='org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat',
                          key_type='org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
                          value_type='org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
                          key_converter=None):

    rdds = []
    for gcs_uri in gcs_uris:

        rdd = spark_context.newAPIHadoopFile(gcs_uri,
                                             input_format,
                                             key_type,
                                             value_type,
                                             keyConverter=key_converter,
                                             conf=hadoop_conf).cache()
        # we only care about the values, the keys are the byte offsets of each value
        rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x[1])
        rdds.append(rdd)
    return spark_context.union(rdds)

#Reading files from GCS (I'm reading 6 files)
rdd = get_rdd_from_gcs_uris(sc, gcs_uris, GCS_CONNECTOR_HADOOP_CONF).cache()

#Counting lines for the first time. This is suppose to be slow
rdd.count()

#Counting lines for the second time. It's 10x faster than the first time, but it takes 4 seconds
tic = time.time()
rdd.count()
print('Count took %.2f seconds' % ((time.time() - tic) / 1000))
```

Comment: You have less than 2Gb of data, which can easily fit on a single machine. Processing it sequentially will be much faster. Use Spark for data sets that don't fit in memory. There is a overhead for scheduling tasks and transferring results, as well as general framework computation that you're not accounting for.

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: It seems small-data and simple job.  As Dan said, sequencial processing will be fast. (Start one thread or process for each source, count  it, join and sum)  And I think you don't need map().  Just use count() for each rdd and sum the results.

Answer (score 3):

Tips:

1. Use Scala (or Java) instead of Python. I don't have a citation for this, but it seems common sense that interfacing the two languages will add inefficiency. Each executor will run a Python process and communicate with it over a pipe.
2. Do not `union` RDDs. You can pass a "glob" (e.g. `path/*.csv`) to `newAPIHadoopFile` and it returns an RDD made up of all files that match. (This should not affect `count` after caching though.)
3. On the Storage tab of the Spark UI check what fraction of the RDD is cached. Maybe it's not 100%.
4. Don't measure seconds. Work with more data and measure minutes. A JVM can spend 4 seconds just doing GC.
5. Try with more or less partitions. You have 57 partitions and 16 executor threads. So each executor thread will have to ask for more work several times. Try it with 16 partitions, so they only have to ask once.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try these suggestions and let you know what I've found.